# Left outer join with specific record in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables first `Audit_exception` and second `finding_escalation`. I need to join both the table using left outer join. Each record/exception in audit_exception table having corresponding record in finding_escalation table but there might be no corresponding records or having single record or multiple records. Basically 1:M relationship.

Tables

Audit_Exception

| Objid | Exception_id | Description | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Abcd | Abcd |

Finding_escalation

| Objid | Finding_objid | Esc_level | Esc_type | Latest_esc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1234 | 1 | Escalation | 1 |
| 10002 | 1234 | 1 | Warning | 0 |

Requirement : I need to join both the table but only with latest escalation record if multiple record is present in `finding_escalation` table. If no record is present in `finding_escalation` table then according to left outer join the only data of Audit_exception should be in output  result.

Problem : If I am using normal left outer join then I am getting multiple records in output query if finding_escalation table having multiple records for same finding.  I can’t use ANSI standard LEFT OUTER JOIN ON keyword because query is written oracle based (+) operator syntax. How to add extra condition on joining so that join will happen with finding_escalation latest record only.

Query 1 :

```sql
select * from audit_exception ae, finding_escalation esc 
where ae.objid = esc.finding_objid (+) 
and ae.objid=1234;
```

This query is working fine when `finding_escaltion` table having no record or single record the output is single record. But resulting with multiple records when `finding_escalation` table also having multiple records.

Query 2:

```sql
select * from audit_exception ae, finding_escalation esc
where ae.objid = esc.finding_objid (+)
and esc.LATEST_RECORD = 1
and ae.objid=1234
```

This query is working fine when `finding_escaltion` table having single or multiple records. But not working if there is no records in `finding_escaltion` table, the output is blank.

My expectation : I need a single output irrespective of finding_escalation table has any record or multiple records or no records.

Please let me know if my query is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the filter in the join condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   audit_exception ae
       LEFT OUTER JOIN finding_escalation esc
       ON (    ae.objid = esc.finding_objid
           and esc.LATEST_RECORD = 1)
WHERE  ae.objid=1234
```

Or, using the legacy syntax (don't use it, convert to the ANSI/ISO syntax):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   audit_exception ae,
       finding_escalation esc
WHERE  ae.objid = esc.finding_objid (+)
AND    esc.LATEST_RECORD (+) = 1
AND    ae.objid=1234
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Audit_Exception (Objid, Exception_id, Description, "COMMENT") AS
SELECT 1234, 1, 'Abcd', 'Abcd' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Finding_escalation (Objid, Finding_objid, Esc_level, Esc_type, Latest_record) AS
SELECT 10001, 1234, 1, 'Escalation', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, 1234, 1, 'Warning',    0 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | OBJID | EXCEPTION_ID | DESCRIPTION | COMMENT | OBJID | FINDING_OBJID | ESC_LEVEL | ESC_TYPE | LATEST_RECORD |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 1 | Abcd | Abcd | 10001 | 1234 | 1 | Escalation | 1 |

If you then do:

```sql
DELETE FROM finding_escalation;
```

Then the output is:

> | OBJID | EXCEPTION_ID | DESCRIPTION | COMMENT | OBJID | FINDING_OBJID | ESC_LEVEL | ESC_TYPE | LATEST_RECORD |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 1 | Abcd | Abcd | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d766a5565dfb06c76befb41b0c9b077)*

Comment: I have to solve using oracle (+) operator only. The existing query is very large with multiple tables. I have just posted the problem part. I can't change that large query using LEFT OUTER JOIN and ON keyword.

Comment: @Randhir I gave a solution using the legacy `(+)` operator in the answer before you commented.